# Reusing content-encryption key in cms enveloped data

Tags: openssl, key-management, key-generation, cms

OpenSSL keeps the structure `CMS_ContentInfo` opaque and in the case of enveloped data generates and manages the content-encryption key completely by itself. It is not possible to provide a content-encryption key generated by yourself.

In contrast to that Bouncy Castle allows a more individual content-encryption key management via the `OutputEncryptor` interface.

Now my questions are:

- Is this intentional? In [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-6) of RFC 5652 neither approach is explicitly recommended.
- The Bouncy Castle approach allows the reuse of the same content-encryption key for several enveloped data containers. Is this a severe security issue and if yes, why?